# Calculation returns NaN with dynamic values

Tags: javascript, math, nan

The following calculation works fine if I code the values by hand, but with dynamic values I always end up with NaN.

```
vals.tension = Math.round( ( Math.pow( ( vals.frequency * ( vals.stringLength * 10 ) * vals.diameter ), 2 ) * ( Math.PI * vals.density / 9810000000000 ) ) * 100 ) / 100;
```

If I add the following values it all works fine:

```
Math.round( ( Math.pow( ( 389.723 * ( 66 * 10 ) * .44 ), 2 ) * ( Math.PI * 1300 / 9810000000000 ) ) * 100 ) / 100;
// 5.33
```

If I write out the values by hand it also works ok:

```
var vals = {
frequency: 389.723,
stringLength: 66,
diameter: .44,
density: 1300
};
```

But if I try to dynamically re-create exactly the same values via user input I get NaN. I've checked the values via console.log and they are EXACTLY the same (they're not strings) and they all get added ok to the object, but the actual calculation when preformed dynamically (in Safari) returns NaN.

Comment: are you sure they aren't strings?

Comment: If the values were "_exactly the same_" then you wouldn't be having a problem, would you! I know you said that they're not strings, but I still bet that they are.

Comment: seems to be a tricky problem. plz reproduce your problem on http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: I use parseFloat when adding the values to the object, they're not strings...

Comment: Hmm, I think the numbers are going out of range... `Math.PI * 1300 / 9810000000000;
// 4.1631706928305107e-10` Any easy fix to avoid so gosh darn many decimal places?!!

Comment: AAGH! So sorry to have wasted your time. Was a typo in my code :P dorkus makimus. Apologies all round.

Answer (score 1):

try to use parseFloat() or parseInt() functions. The delimiter between decimal and float part for parseFloat should be dot.
And you may use Isnumeric() in condition before calculation to make sure that it is right input

Comment: Thanks Fedor - see my comment below.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your user input into parseFloat() function

Comment: Hi Jura, thanks for the suggestion I actually already tried this, but it didn't seem to help. Figure it's a good idea to do in any case!